# CSS works in chrome developer tools but not on actual mobile device

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, media-queries

[Contact form in Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uqHd.jpg)

[Contact form on Chrome for Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krY9S.jpg)

As you can see from the pictures the CSS is not working on the actual mobile device. I'm using media queries to style on mobile.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Already using the viewport meta.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

[Live Webpage I'm having issues with.](http://www.danieldolecki.com/heartsthatheal/contact.php) Work in progress.

Edit:

Here is pretty much what it was. Except with this I have no issues. I even copy and pasted the entirety of the css into that html and it worked as it should, but for whatever reason it doesn't work on the original.

## HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">   
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="queries.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="contact-body-color">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="contact-body">
                    <form method="post" action="mailer.php" class="contact-form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="">
                                <label for="fName lName">Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="first-name">
                                <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" placeholder="First name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="last-name">
                                <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" placeholder="Last name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <label for="find-us">Subject</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="subject">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Your subject" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
                                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
*   {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body    {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    min-width: 340px;
}

.row    {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* ----- QUOTE ----- */

.contact-body {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #92b296;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #000000;
}

.contact-body-color {
    background-color: #575367;
}

.contact-form {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contact-form .first-name {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.contact-form .last-name {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.contact-form .subject {
    width: 50%;
}

.contact-form input[type=text] {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.contact-form input[type=email] {
    width: 45%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.contact-form input[type=text],
.contact-form input[type=email],
.contact-form textarea  {
    margin: 5px 0 15px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #666;
}

.contact-form textarea {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.contact-form label {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333;
}

.contact-form input[type=submit], 
.contact-form input[type=reset] {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #be6876;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #666;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.contact-form input[type=submit]:active,
.contact-form input[type=reset]:active {
    transform: translate(2px, 2px);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #666;
}
```

## Queries

```
/* Big tablets to 1200px (widths smaller than the 1140px row) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px)   {

    .row    { padding: 0 10px; }

}

/* Small phones to small tablets: from 481px to 767px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)   {


    /* ----- Contact Form ----- */
    .contact-body {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 40px;
    }

    .contact-form {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .contact-form .first-name,
    .contact-form .last-name,
    .contact-form .subject,
    .contact-form input[type=text], 
    .contact-form input[type=email] {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .contact-form input[type=text],
    .contact-form input[type=email],
    .contact-form textarea  {
        margin: 5px 0 15px 0;
    }

    .contact-form textarea {
        height: 200px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .contact-form label {
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #333;
    }

    .contact-form input[type=submit], 
    .contact-form input[type=reset] {
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        width: 48%;
    }

    .contact-form input[type=submit]    {
        margin-right: 2%;
    }

    .contact-form .buttons {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }


}


/* Small phones: from 0 to 480px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)   {

    .row {
        padding: 0;
    }

}
```

## Edit 2:

It's an issue with chrome for android. Downloaded firefox on my phone and it works and looks fine.

Comment: Rather than link to a page (which could rot) please provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: Did you use bootstrap? if not you can add @media query in your own css and change style, width if you are in small devices

Comment: No bootstrap used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled chrome on my phone. Now everything works fine. Must have needed an update.

Comment: You can't accept your own answer until two days after its posted.

Comment: I'm newbie, sorry for that!

Comment: No worries, so am I.

Answer (score 0):

Check if adding `display: block;` under `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)` solves your issue. On my mobile browser version looks fine.

```
.contact-form .first-name,
.contact-form .last-name,
.contact-form .subject,
.contact-form input[type=text], 
.contact-form input[type=email] {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Tried to no avail. I pulled it up on a smaller iPhone and gs6+ than my gs9+. It all looked perfect. I'm guessing that it has to do with the Galaxy S9+ being massive, thought it shouldn't as it has the same view-port dimensions as the gs6+.

Comment: Oh yeah makes sense. In that case you'll need to add a media query specifically designed for your device. Trying to find out what resolution the browser displays the content to update the answer.

Comment: The only thing is it's adding and removing padding to other elements on the page that should never look like they do on the GS9+. I'll have to mess around with it.